# Understanding subject change in「馬鹿みたい子供なのね」

Tags: subjects

I'm looking to start learning casual speech through different songs I like and using translated lyrics to decipher the meaning. The first phrase of the song 馬鹿みたい is giving me some confusion. In 馬鹿みたい子供なのね how do we know we've gone from talking about the speaker **馬鹿みたい** to about a "you" in **子供なのね**?

Comment: No one can tell from that alone who's like a fool and who's like a child. What made you think those are two different people?

Answer (score 1):

They are two sentences.

> ばかみたい You are a fool/That's ridiculous.
>
> 子供なのね You are a baby, aren't you?

Basically you need to be able to guess the subject correctly here.

---

Just my impression, but learning exclusively from song lyrics wouldn't be a good way to learn. They are composed often in the way you need to guess a lot, due to the constraints posed by the tune.

Comment: Adam (and any other interested readers), as [@sundowner](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/users/45489/) notes, these are two separate sentences.  One way we can tell this is that みたい requires な if it is used to modify a following noun.  Since the noun こども comes directly after みたい, but _without_ that required な, we can tell that ばかみたい is **not** being used to modify the noun こども, and is instead a complete sentence unto itself.